# Developer vs. General accounts w/ DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

A few weeks ago I implemented my first REST integration with the DocuSign API. Things over all went smoothly and with very little complaints. One particular hang up I experienced though was some confusion in regards to the Developer account and how it relates to the General account. I started with a developer account and used the test credentials to build my integration. Once my integration passed inspection it required me to choose another paid docusign account that the integration key would "go live" on. This is all pretty straight forward.

The curve ball came when I actually went to purchase the API account and it said, "you aren't eligible to purchase this". There isn't clear instruction on the site, so my questions are:

1.) In what order does the account creation need to go? Developer > General (Paid) > API Plan (Paid)?

2.) Does DocuSign expect the user, as the customer, to purchase the plan or should that plan be purchased through my developer account?

I tried to reach out to customer service directly, but it was pretty much a, "give us all of your money, then we'll help" situation. I have several customers who are interested in this integration, but I'm not comfortable presenting this as an option until I get a better understanding of the process. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general, DocuSign does require a paid account to complete the Go Live process. If you - the integration owner - will not be using DocuSign yourself, you would want to reach out to the [DocuSign Partners program][1] to receive a free Partner account that can hold your integration key instead of having to purchase one.
From there, the end users of your integration can purchase their own DocuSign accounts. You could potentially act as a reseller of DocuSign if you were so inclined.

https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner

If you still need assistance, please email apihelp@docusign.com with this information. Someone will help you right away.